# How can I get the downloads to start automatically after buying something on the web store?

Tags: ps4

When I purchased a game or DLC on the Xbox Marketplace (.com), the purchases would be downloaded automatically whenever I turned on my console.

However, it does not seem to work like this on the PlayStation 4. Buying anything from the PS Store Online, the games do not automatically appear on my PS4.

The only way to get the things I bought on the web site seems to be to open the Store on my console, searching up the item, and purchasing them again at no cost.

Is there a more convenient way of doing this, preferably automatic?

Comment: check your purchases/download list on the console; should be easier to find there

Comment: As long as you put your PS4 into standby, instead of shutting it down entirely, it should eventually start downloading new purchases automatically. Not sure if it requires a PS Plus subscription or not; I think it doesn't.

Comment: @Nolonar I can confirm that it does not require a PS Plus subscription.

Answer (score 5):

You first need to change the settings on your PS4 so that you can connect to the Internet while in Standby mode. Then, when you're done playing with the PS4, always put it on stand-by. When you buy something from the store, you will also need to "Queue" the download to your console. You can do this from the "Download List" on the Store.